# Getting selected item from Treeview

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a TreeView and want to get the selected item from it.

The Treeview itself is populated not manually, but from data in the code. Since it is populated this way, I'm not sure how to get information out of it.

Here is the XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="trvFamilies" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,3,3" Width="340">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:Scene}" ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="New" Click="MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"></MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageSceneRegular}" Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="64" Height="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Characters.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:Character}">

                    <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="AliceBlue" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4" Background="White">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Img}" Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="64" Height="64" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" (" Foreground="Green" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Foreground="Green" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" years)" Foreground="Green" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

It is populated by data from an ObservableCollection which is populated within the code and then assigned to the ItemSource of the treeview (and it works fine).

So let's say I had a TextBlock which sat outside the TreeView and wanted to populate it with information from the selected Character (that's the type which populates the drop down part of the TreeView), I don't know how to do that, be it using XAML only or code behind.

Any help on how to do this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just access trvFamilies.SelectedItem?